# Inf and sup of an intersection and union of 2 sets

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I'm looking for an example when there is **no supremum** of an **intersection** of 2 sets, also no supremum of an **union** (not the same example).

**Each set needs to have a supremum**, but not their intersection. Same goes for the union.

I'd really appreciate same example for infimum.

(I do undersand what all of the mentioned above are, I just struggle with finding a suitable example.)

Comment: What is the universe of these sets? Because $\sup$ and $\inf$ are defined on sets containing ordered elements.

Comment: If the universe is the reals, then the union example you want isn't possible.

Comment: What about naturals or integers? I do not know what the universe is supposed to be, the problem was presented to me like this.

Comment: Same problem with any subset of the reals.

Comment: But are you talking about the union or also about interjection? 
I was thinking what if it was for example an interjection between sets [1,2,3] and [7,8] ? Then their interjection is empty so it cannot have a supremum. Does that make sense?

Comment: And as to the union I couldn't come up with anything, but my teacher believes it exists.

Comment: I only mentioned union :P. I can prove union doesn't exist. If $A\cup B$ has no supremum while $\sup A=a$, $\sup B=b$, note that there must exist some $x\in A\cup B$ such that $x>a,b$, since otherwise, $A\cup B$ would be bounded from above, and by the supremum property, it has a supremum. But, $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, violating the supremum of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: You're right.. Does infinity have supremum?

Comment: No, it's not a real.